# If using or statment

Tags: vb.net

Can anybody please explain why visual studio does not like the or in the if statement.

I know I can get the same job done by using `elseif`, but I am trying to understand why the or does not work.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim input As String = "asdcessssf"
        Dim count As Integer
        Dim totalchar As Integer
        Dim final As Integer

        For Each ch As Char In input
            If ch = "a" Or "e" Then
                count += 1
                totalchar += 1

            Else
                totalchar += 1

            End If

        Next
        final = (count / totalchar) * 100
        MsgBox(final)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The correct syntax for `Or` is `If ch = "a" Or ch = "e" Then`

Answer (score 1):

You are formulating condition in wrong manner. This should be `ch = "a" Or ch="e"`. You are missing the `ch =` after `Or`

Answer (score 0):

In a Boolean comparison, the Or operator always evaluates both expressions, which could include making procedure calls. The OrElse Operator (Visual Basic) performs short-circuiting, which means that if expression1 is True, then expression2 is not evaluated.
 You can use OrElse to get short-circuiting behaviour.

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude but I think you missed the point a little. The reason the code is failing is not because of the use of `Or`. It's because they aren't checking if `ch` actually does equal `"e"`. This would also fail `If ch = "a" OrElse "e"` in other words.

Comment: that also must be true i haven't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

As explain with "pmatyszok" you have missing `"ch="e"` after `or`,and i suggest you also  to optimase your code as :

```
 For Each ch As Char In input
       If ch = "a" Or ch = "e" Then count += 1
        totalchar += 1
 Next
```